# Recursive removing of directories

Tags: java, recursion, rm

I am trying to remove a directory recursively. But I've got some problems. 
So, I create in my "test" folder some directories as it shown on the picture. But in in 3rd folder it throws an exception java.lang.NullPointerException.

Here's the picture and some code:

```
public static void RecursiveRm (String myFile)
{
    File fl = new File(myFile);
    String [] temp = fl.list();
    if(temp.length > 0){
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; ++i){
            myFile = myFile + "/" + temp[i];
            RecursiveRm(myFile);
        }
    }
    else
        fl.delete();
}
```

That's how it works

[image: That's how it works]

Comment: Could you tell us what exception it is throwing? (NullPointerException, IOException, etc.)

Comment: Add the whole stacktrace please.

Comment: Sure, it's added in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing this for a start.

```
myFile = myFile + "/" + temp[i];
```

This means that if you have a directory with `a` `b` and `c` in it the path will become `/a/b/c` You should avoid changing `myFile`

Try this instead.

```
for(String file: new File(myFile).list()) {
    recursiveRm(myFile + "/" + file);
}
fl.delete();
```

Most likely you are getting a NullPointerException as `File.list()` return `null` if the directory doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

After looking at your code, you are getting a NullPointerException from fl.list() when no subdirectory is found. In your code change:

```
if(temp.length > 0)
```

to

```
if(temp != null && temp.length > 0)
```

Full changed code:

```
public static void RecursiveRm (String myFile)
{
    File fl = new File(myFile);
    String [] temp = fl.list();
    if(temp != null && temp.length > 0){
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; ++i){
            myFile = myFile + "/" + temp[i];
            RecursiveRm(myFile);
        }
    }

    fl.delete();
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's the problem as it mentioned on the picture. Thank you =)

Comment: Sorry, I re-ran it and realized that there was a logic error. Remove the 'else'

I have updated and tested my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would really like to accept your answer but Peter's looks more laconically. I'm sorry(